# Best practice for method chaining ("return this")

Tags: c#, .net, return-value

I have an abstract class called `DatabaseRow` that, after being derived and constructed, is mainly loaded from a `Load(object id)` method.

I have lots of code that creates a new instance of the class, loads it from an ID, then returns the class. I'd like to simplify this code into one line of code (just to be neat, there are plenty of classes that will just have lists of properties that return these Loaded instances).

There are two ways I can think of doing it, but neither seem 'right' to me.

**1.** I could `return this;` at the end of my `Load` method and use `return new Derived().Load(id);`

**2.** I could create a generic method to return a loaded method.

```
public static T LoadRow<T>(object id) where T : DatabaseRow, new()
{
    T row = new T();
    row.Load(id);
    return row;
}
```

I've seen some other code that uses the same method as number **1**, but I've never seen any experienced developer recommend it, nor have I came across any methods in the .NET framework that do the same thing, so maybe this isn't best practice?

Does anybody know of any other solutions that could be better than both of these?

**Solution:**

After reading SirViver's answer and comment, I realised that all the properties being returned need to be cached anyway. The solution was sightly different, but similar to option **2** (that I wouldn't expect anyone to come up with this answer as I didn't explain this part of the design)

All these instances will be loaded from a value retrieved from another column in the database (database relationships if you like). Instead of trying to load the new instance from this value, I made a method to load the instance from the column name and cache the loaded value in a Dictionary. This works well as this is one of the primary functions of the `DatabaseRow` class.

```
    private Dictionary<string, DatabaseRow> linkedRows;

    protected T GetLinkedRow<T>(string key) where T : DatabaseRow, new()
    {
        if (linkedRows.ContainsKey(key)) return (T)linkedRows[key];
        else
        {
            T row = new T();
            row.Load(this[key]);
            linkedRows.Add(key, row);
            return row;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I think it's bad practice to chain method calls that have actual sideffects on the object instance. To be honest, I think both examples are quite ugly "hacks" whose only purpose is saving two lines of code. I don't think the result is actually more readable either.

If you want a record to be loaded immediately, I'd probably rather supply a constructor variant that takes the ID you load from and make the object auto-populate itself on construction, though when I think about it, I wouldn't bother at all to be honest - cramming more information in a single line does not make for more read- and maintainable code.

Comment: In my case, I have a class that inherits `DatabaseRow`, and have 5 properties which all use this same function. Having 5 lines of code, similar to `public Derived MyProperty { get { return new Derived().Load(myInt); } }` would be much neater than separating the properties into multi-line code.

Comment: But how does the "neatness" of the property code matter at all? In most cases the property code should be collapsed by Visual Studio anyway, and it's not like you constantly have to look at the class implementation anyway. That said, constructing and loading data on a property access seems quite dangerous to begin with. If someone doesn't know that the result needs to be cached this could quickly result in bad performance and/or unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thats it!!! I feel like such an idiot now. Your comment on caching reminded me that I've already created this function right at the bottom of my DatabaseRow class! `protected T GetLinkedRow<T>(string key) where T : DatabaseRow, new()` loads the row and caches it in a dictionary based on the value of `key`.

Comment: Since I agree with everything you said your first paragraph and your comment triggered my solution, I feel this should be the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Number 1 is gaining in popularity in some circles; it's often called *fluent programming* when there's an interface that defines great numbers of these methods and long chains can be assembled. The key to doing this successfully is never to define a method that sometimes returns `this`, but other times returns `null`. If `this` is always returned (unless there's an exception) it's perfectly good style.

Personally I'm not as fond of solutions like number 2, as it could be said to violate the "one responsibility" principle.

Answer (score 1):

Although I personally like methods returning `this` as it allows them to be chained, I think in the .NET framework (up until Linq), this was frowned upon. The reason that pops to mind is this:

Methods either return a result or change the state of the object. Returning `this` is a bit of both: Changing the state of the object and then returning a "result" - except that result is the modified original object. This doesn't fit the expectations of the user.

What about:

```
public class Derived : DatabaseRow
{
    public Derived(object id):
    {
        Load(id);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
return new Derived(id);
```

Comment: I couldn't agree more with your second paragraph here. I was actually originally using something similar to your solution, however I decided against it and changed to the Load method because I don't think constructors should have that much functionality (in this case, executing SQL queries)

Comment: @Connell Watkins: I have thought similarly about constructors before myself, but now tend to think of them as being a guarantee that the object is in a usable state. So, if the objects are only ever meant to be used after calling the Load method, then you really can put that in the constructor!

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is only acceptable if it is possible to have a row without being loaded. This is due to the pattern allowing you to do this:

```
return new Derived();
```

Personally I would prefer the static method. But I suspect it is simply a matter of personal preference.

As ssg says the other option (lets call it option 3) is to overload the constructor in Derived which would also work, however having lots of constructors can often be confusing as the calling code does not have anything in it which describes what is going on.

Option 1:

```
return new Derived().Load(10);
```

Option 2:

```
return Derived.Load(10);
```

Option 3:

```
return new Derived(10);
```

Option 1 looks like you are getting a superfluous object created. Option 2 is good because it does what it looks like it is doing. Option 3 leaves confusion about what it does.

Comment: It is quite possible to have a class and not load it. If you were creating a new row in the database, you'd create a new instance, fill the properties and then call a `Save()` method. Do you mean the generic static method? Or a static method in each derived class?

Comment: Ah, I've just seen your edit. Option 2 looks perfect, but the thing with that is that it would require me to create the same static method for every derived class of this type, which seems to be unnecessary.